# Many to many query: find words that have only checked phrases

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have `word` model and `phrase` model

```
class Word(models.Model): 
        checked = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Phrase(models.Model):
    words = models.ManyToManyField(Word, null=True,related_name = "phrases")
```

`Word` model has attribute `checked` and many to many connection to `phrase`

I need to perfom a difficult for me query:

- We are considering that phrase `is checked` if it has at least one
  `checked` word.
- How do I find all words that has **only** checked phrases and **doesn't have** `unchecked` phrases?

Right now I am doing using cycle through all words in db, but this is not very effective, so I am looking for more efficient way to do this.

Comment: What about `Phrase`s with no `Word`s and vice versa?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `Phrase` will always have at least one `Word` and `Word` will always have at least one `Phrase`

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in two steps:

```
non_checked_phrases=Phrase.objects.exclude(word__checked=True)
non_checked_words = Word.objects.exclude(phrases__in=non_checked_phrases)
```

First we thus obtain a `QuerySet` of the `Phrases` where no of the related words are checked. Next we obtain a `QuerySet` where we eclude all words that have a related phrase in the previously generated `QuerySet`.

This will generate a query like:

```
SELECT word.*
FROM word
WHERE NOT (word.id IN
    (SELECT pw1.`word_id`
     FROM phrase_word AS pw1
     WHERE pw1.phrase_id IN
         (SELECT p.`id`
          FROM `auth_group` AS p
          WHERE NOT (V0.`id` IN
              (SELECT pw2.`phrase_id`
               FROM phrase_word AS pw2
               INNER JOIN word AS w2 ON pw2.word_id = w2.id
               WHERE w2.is_active = True
             )
         ))
    )
)
```

Comment: okay, I have a problem with exclude - can you look at this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51754025/django-performance-issue-with-exclude